# How do I add jquery to my MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, how can I add the link/script below to my project and change the styling to suit.

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" 

rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the jQuery js and CSS file links to your master layout page in the header (or js files in the footer if you dont need them to load right away).

you can add your own css files after the jquery css files if you want to overwrite the styles.

Comment: just not sure how I can take jquery from jquery-ui site and add to my project.

Comment: the jQuery CDN lets you link to them, its best because that means users will load your page faster, and will download the jQuery files from another web server. usually you will already have jQuery in your project if its a new MVC application, check your Scripts folder?

Comment: if it is not there you can install it from here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery and http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@Scripts.Render` method for this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/jquery")
```

The above bundles the whole directory so you do not need to include it file by file.

And `Styles.Render` method for CSS files (localated within a given directory):

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

You can read more about bundling and minification in ASP.NET MVC [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

In case you use older versions of ASP.NET MVC you could simply do this in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")"></script>
```